# .htaccess HTTPS redirect except one page laravel

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I want to redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP except urls that contain this string:
"/account/buy-premium"

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/account/buy-premium [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/buy-premium [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller... Default Laravel conf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**https:// example.com/test-page** is redirecting to **http:// example.com/test-page** (good)

But

https://example.com/account/buy-premium/991 is redirecting to http://example.com/index.php (bad - no redirect is needed here)

I cannot find any solution to prevent redirect for the /buy-premium page
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` since `REQUEST_URI` changes to `/index.php` by your very last rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/account/buy-premium [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/account/buy-premium [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller... Default Laravel conf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```